# Move files and copy subtree

Tags: find, xargs

```
source="/somedir/dir-a"
dest="/somedir2/dir-z"
```

I need to find all files recursively within the **$source** directory which contain the string **720p** and move them to **$dest**

Just 2 things to take care of -

1. For all such files which are to be moved , first create that file's outer 2 directories in **$dest** and then move this matched file inside that
2. i have to do this for lakhs of files so a bit of parallelization would be helpful

Example
For a file like - `"$source/dir-b/dir-c/file-720p.mp4"` , it should do as follows :

1. `mkdir -p "$dest/dir-b/dir-c"`
2. `mv "$source/dir-b/dir-c/file-720p.mp4" "$dest/dir-b/dir-c/file-720p.mp4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```sh
src=foo
dst=bar
export dst
find "${src}" -name '*720p*' -type f -exec sh -c '
for p; do
  np=${dst}${p#"${p%/*/*/*}"}
  echo mkdir -p "${np%/*}" &&
  echo mv "$p" "$np"
done' sh {} +
```

This can be parallelized using GNU find's **-print0** primary in conjunction with GNU xargs, but I don't think that'd make much of a difference performance-wise, as this is rather an IO-intensive task.

Remove `echo`s if the output is satisfactory.